# Webpack CSS Loader - Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file'

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am getting this error when trying to use CSS-Loader...

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file'`

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Poorly named error. To fix,

`npm install --save file-loader`

Module "file" is actually `file-loader` but the syntax removes the word loader for some reason.

Comment: I think that your config contains something like `loaders : [ 'file', ... ]`, and Webpack tries both `file` and `file-loader` and gives up if it can't find any of those modules.

Comment: I have the file loader installed but I still get this error.  It's also on a 'required' css file that's a slightly newer version of the one I was using previously and in a different location. All I did was change the path to the newer version of the file and now I get this error.  I'm using webpack 1.13.2